# How to export one database from phpmyadmin with wget

Tags: phpmyadmin, automation, wget

I have a database that I manage through PHPMyAdmin.
I often export it in a sql backup file using the [Export] tab.
It produces a 300MB file.

I would like to make this process easier and automatic.

I wrote the following script with the help of many forum posts :

```
#!/bin/sh

ADMIN_URL='http://pma.example.net'
USERNAME='xxxxx'
PASSWORD='xxxxx'
DATABASE='xxxxx'
COOKIEJAR='/tmp/my_cookiejar'

post_data="pma_username=$USERNAME&pma_password=$PASSWORD"

token=$(
    wget -qO- \
         --keep-session-cookies \
         --post-data "$post_data" \
         --save-cookies "$COOKIEJAR" \
         "$ADMIN_URL/" \
    | egrep -om1 'token=[[:xdigit:]]+'
)

post_data="$token&what=sql&export_type=server&sql_structure_or_data=structure_and_data"

wget -O export.sql \
     --keep-session-cookies \
     --load-cookies "$COOKIEJAR" \
     --post-data "$post_data" \
     "$ADMIN_URL/export.php"
```

It works but it exports all databses when I just want to export one database.

I tried to use :

```
post_data="$token&what=sql&export_type=database&db=$DATABASE&sql_structure_or_data=structure_and_data"
```

But it doesn't download anything.

Can you help me out?
Thanks for your help.

Santiago

Answer (score 1):

I used your script with a small modification. Works OK with phpMyAdmin 3.3.8.1

For what you want, the key is:

```
&db_select[0]=${DATABASE}
```

Assuming your phpMyAdmin version uses the same parameter name.

Here's the full modified script:

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                     

ADMIN_URL='http://pma.example.net'
USERNAME='xxxxx'                                
PASSWORD='xxxxx'                                 
DATABASE='xxxxx'                                
COOKIEJAR='/tmp/my_cookiejar'                          

post_data="pma_username=$USERNAME&pma_password=$PASSWORD"

token=$(
    wget -qO- \
         --keep-session-cookies \
         --post-data "$post_data" \
         --save-cookies "$COOKIEJAR" \
         "$ADMIN_URL/" \              
    | egrep 'token=[[:xdigit:]]+' | head -n 1 | awk -F\' '{print $2}'
)                                                                    

post_data="$token\
&what=sql\
&export_type=server\
&asfile=sendit\
&compression=bzip\
&db_select[0]=${DATABASE}\
&sql_include_comments=something\
&sql_compatibility=NONE\
&sql_structure=something\
&sql_drop_database=something\
&sql_if_not_exists=something\
&sql_auto_increment=something\
&sql_backquotes=something\
&sql_data=something\
&sql_columns=something\
&sql_extendede=something\
&sql_max_query_size=50000\
&sql_type=INSERT\
"

wget -O ${DATABASE}_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M).sql.bz2 \
     --keep-session-cookies \
     --load-cookies "$COOKIEJAR" \
     --post-data "$post_data" \
     "$ADMIN_URL/export.php"
```

The reason for the egrep change was to make it work with BusyBox v1.01, apparently that version of egrep has no "o" and "m" options.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be possible or may be hard to do.
The best way would for you to be able to use the backup tools supplied by MySQL. (Like mysqldump)